# How to create set of Multiple JSON with same header

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, json.net

> I have a JSON that has the following pattern to be created before
>   hitting the API, See below

```
    "recipientSetInfos":    
     [
          {
            "recipientSetMemberInfos":          
            [
              {
                "fax": "",
                "email": ""
              }
            ],
            "recipientSetRole":         
            {
              "SIGNER": "enum",
              "APPROVER": "enum"
            },
            "signingOrder": 0
          }
        ]
```

> Using this predefined Format, i want to create Multiple signer set's,
>   like the below.

```
   "recipientSetInfos": 
    [
      {
        "recipientSetMemberInfos": 
        [{

            "email": "def@gmail.com"
        }],
        "recipientSetRole": "SIGNER"
    }, {
        "recipientSetMemberInfos": [{

            "email": "abc@gmail.com"
        }],
        "recipientSetRole": "SIGNER"
    }],
```

> I am using C# Programming Language, if i just hard code it & send. It
>   works but if i want to create dynamically. How can i achieve this.
>   Currently I am using this like

```
        RecipientSetInfo rec_Info = new RecipientSetInfo();
        rec_Info.recipientSetMemberInfos = List_Emails;
        rec_Info.recipientSetRole = "SIGNER";
        List_Recipients.Add(rec_Info);
```

> which gives an output of :

```
          {
            "recipientSetMemberInfos":
                [
                    {"email":"abc@ae.com"},
                    {"email":"def@gmail.com"},
                    {"email":"fgh@gmail.com"}
                ],
            "recipientSetRole":"SIGNER"
           }
```

> But using this logic, i am not getting the desired output. It is
>   considering all 3 emails as one.

Just to add, one more thing with the help of one user, i tried to code out this

```
foreach (var email in List_Emails)
{
    var rec_Info = new RecipientSetInfo();
    rec_Info.recipientSetRole = "SIGNER";
    List_Recipients.Add(rec_Info);
}
```

But problem still exists, since "recipientSetInfos" has two subdivisions i.e. recipientSetRole & recipientSetMemberInfos within which "recipientSetMemberInfos" has one attribute Email.

So when i add the two lists together it comes out Email to be Null

```
"recipientSetInfos":
[
    {"recipientSetMemberInfos":null,
     "recipientSetRole":"SIGNER"
    ‌​},
    {"recipientSetMemberInfos":null,
     "recipientSetRole":"SIGNER"
    }
]
```

Structure for both the elements i have created like -

```
public class RecipientSetMemberInfo
    {
        public string email { get; set; }
    }

    public class RecipientSetInfo
    {
        public List<RecipientSetMemberInfo> recipientSetMemberInfos { get; set; }
        public string recipientSetRole { get; set; }
    }
```

> Please suggest ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you create **one** `RecipientSetInfo` instead of **one for each email**.

The following will loop through `List_Emails` collection and will add them to the list `List_Recipients`.

```
foreach (var email in List_Emails)
{
    var rec_Info = new RecipientSetInfo();
    rec_Info.recipientSetRole = "SIGNER";
    List_Recipients.Add(rec_Info);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I tried this way too. 

Problem that is coming when i am merging both lists is that List_Emails gets me null emails. Where as if i add quick watch & check it does have email values there.
See the exaple below :

"recipientSetInfos":[{"recipientSetMemberInfos":null,"recipientSetRole":"SIGNER"},{"recipientSetMemberInfos":null,"recipientSetRole":"SIGNER"},{"recipientSetMemberInfos":null,"recipientSetRole":"SIGNER"},{"recipientSetMemberInfos":null,"recipientSetRole":"SIGNER"}]

Comment: Could you publish `List_Emails` class type in full ?

Comment: `foreach (GridViewRow gridRow in grd_signers.Rows)
        {
            TextBox Tb1 = (TextBox)grd_signers.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("Tb_email");

            string Email = string.Empty;
            Email = Tb1.Text;

            RecipientSetMemberInfo rec_MemberInfo2 = new RecipientSetMemberInfo();
            rec_MemberInfo2.email = Email;
            List_Emails.Add(rec_MemberInfo2);

            rowIndex++;
        }`

And my list is getting filled

Comment: Edit your post and add it to the end, so it will be more readable and other people could also answer.

Comment: And I've meant the class structure not creation.

Comment: Sure, I will edit it in the end. Give me few min's i am trying to use your approach in different way . Lets see if it works. 
Otherwise i ll add the query in bottom

Comment: I have provided the structure in my edit. & i tried again using another approach but it doesn't get me the output.

Comment: What is the output of `List_Recipients` after the solution i've provided you ?

Comment: The second last code bit in my question. I have just added after you told me to update

Comment: I've meant the json output.

Comment: First of all really really thank you Orel. I was struggling on this issue from 3 hrs. You pointed me to the right direction & I got wat i wanted..

I just had to refresh the Email list every time & create new between recipients . Doing that used to remove series of email & gets me the email indexes which i wanted .. Thanks again.. Much appreciated ..:)